# Array element reference being set to partially incorrect memory address and data

Tags: c#, pointers, memory, monogame, entity-component-system

I am at the point in the custom ECS I'm making where I am trying to retrieve components I've stored. The issue is when I try to access the array element as a reference it ends up having a memory address that is half right; and the data I return ends up being nothing I've set (should be 150, ends up returning random garbage data).

correct : 0x000000123456789A

what i get : 0xFFFFFFFF3456789A or 0x000000003456789A (always starts with either eight 0's or F's)

When I debug the reference to the array itself visual studio shows that the memory address is pointing to my original array and the data I set is all there. I am not new to C# or pointers; but I am new to the 'ref' keyword, unsafe code, and any of the nuances it may have.

The actual code for trying to return said component reference is :

```
public struct Block
{
    private Array[] components;

    unsafe public readonly ref T Get<T>(int entityID)
    {
        ref ComponentType cType = ref ComponentType.GetInfo<T>();

        ref Array array = ref Components[cType.ID];
        T[] cmp = Unsafe.As<T[]>(array);

        return ref components[entityID];
    }
}
```

I've tried accessing the data in as many ways that I can think of using Unsafe.As casts and even using just raw pointers in a fixed statement; all of which resulted in the same memory address issues as I had above. My current best guess is the references to the arrays are incorrect in a way I don't quite understand, and my index to the element isn't going where I think it's going memory-wise.

Comment: Could the usage of Unsafe.As be avoided, like `T[] components = (T[])array;` ? Because `components[i]` seems to be holding a `T[]` instance, it'd be better to use type safe cast to `T[]`

Comment: @Renat I tried that but it throws an InvalidCastException as all components are stored using the c# Array class, which I am using Array.Resize to expand as I need add components. My 'Set' code looks almost identical to this 'Get' code in that I get the Array my components are stored in and cast it to T[], and that works fine.